# faster ruby json parser in vertx

Tags: json, jruby, vert.x

I'm experiencing a lot of performance issues with to_json, it takes about >100 secs to convert 20 objects to json on the first take and then about >40 on latter calls, oj is not supported in vert.x due to lack of support for C extension, I tried other alternatives like jrjackson, multi_json gem but none gave me a acceptable conversion time, is there any other approach for json conversion or any other gems that I don't know of, any help would be greatly appreciated.

My jruby version is jruby 1.7.18 (1.9.3p551), vertx 2.x